# cannot access eclipse after update

Tags: android, eclipse

Hi i recently updated eclipse but after update it asked me to restart now i am getting the following error and am not able to access it.

**This is the error log.**

```
    !SESSION 2013-01-09 15:20:18.897 -----------------------------------------------
    eclipse.buildId=v21.0.0-531062
    java.version=1.7.0_10
    java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
    BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
    Framework arguments:  -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
    Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui_1.0.200.v20120530-1435.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.pde.ds.ui 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.3.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui_2.7.0.v20120123-1045.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.emf.edit.ui 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench_[3.7.0,4.0.0).
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport_1.0.1.v20110818-1344.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.importexport 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
    !SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.100.v20120530-1425.jar was not resolved.
    !SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-01-09 15:20:42.773
    !MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jdt.core_[3.8.0,4.0.0).

.
.
.
.
.
.
.
.

    !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-01-09 15:20:43.119
    !MESSAGE Application error
    !STACK 1
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.cdt.codan.core.application, org.eclipse.cdt.core.GeneratePDOM, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.garbagecollector.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.InstallPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.EclipseGenerator, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.ProductPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.reconciler.application, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.repo2runnable, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.repository.metadataverifier, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.updatesite.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.UpdateSitePublisher, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.publisher.CategoryPublisher, org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate, org.eclipse.update.core.siteOptimizer, org.eclipse.equinox.p2.installer.application, org.eclipse.help.base.infocenterApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.helpApplication, org.eclipse.help.base.indexTool, org.eclipse.pde.build.Build, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.uitestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.legacytestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplication, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.coretestapplicationnonmain, org.eclipse.pde.junit.runtime.nonuithreadtestapplication.
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi if you have another copy of eclipse without the update then copy that folder into the location where you are using eclipse this should solve your problem. The plugins will also be there only the error will be gone and you can access eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

update JDT i.e. java development kit.I think it is not compatible to your new eclipse.java version may be 3.8.0 or 4.0.0

Comment: i am an android developer..so do i need to update adt??i dont think so thats a problem coz i am already using the latest version of adt

Comment: no need to update ADT. you need to update JDT of version 3.8.0 or 4.0.0, which is compatible on your new eclipse.I have faced the same problem at once.when I update JDT, my problem is solved

Comment: jdk not jdt.which jdk u r using? jus type command like java -version on terminal