# Android - cannot open Eclipse after updating to version 22

Tags: android, eclipse

I have just updated Android SDK plugins to the latest version 22, which forced Eclipse Juno to also update to the same version.
After Eclipse attempted to auto-restart, I am no longer able to open my Android development environment, with the error message appearing:
"An error has occurred. See log file: C:\eclipse\configuration\xxxxx.log

Below is a top section of that log.
Please suggest what I need to do to get it working again.

```
    !SESSION 2013-08-25 23:32:29.187 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20130204-1200
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_NZ
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wb.core_1.5.2.r42x201302111859.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.core 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.core 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wb.swing.java6_1.5.2.r42x201302112024.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.swing.java6 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.swing.java6 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.wb.swing_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.swing.java6 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui_3.6.100.v20120530-1425.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface.text_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt_0.10.3.v20130124-133900.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_[3.5.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler_1.1.0.v20110815-1744.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.query_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_[2.0.0,3.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.5))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.4))(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.1)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui.sdk.scheduler 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.ui.actions_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.wb.discovery.ui_1.5.2.r42x201302111927.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.discovery.ui 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.wb.discovery.ui 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.equinox.p2.ui_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jface.databinding_1.6.0.v20120912-132807.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jface.databinding 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jface.databinding 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.jface_[3.2.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring_1.3.0.20130129-0926.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.compare_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.m2e.refactoring 2 0 2013-08-25 23:32:30.562
!MESSAGE Missing required bundle org.eclipse.ui.workbench_0.0.0.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final and the only solution that worked was to:

1. Go to eclipse home folder (C:\eclipse)
2. Search for word 'android' across all sub-folders (I have used Total Commander file manager)
3. Delete all files related to 'android', as found in the search results.
4. Restart the eclipse.
5. This finally allowed me to re-install the ADT plugin and restart the eclipse
   development environment, WITHOUT the need to re-install the whole thing again. This saved me enormous amount of time, compared to trying to (a) uninstalling eclipse, (b) installing it again, and (c) recreating the whole work environment, including sample apps, libraries, etc., which would take ages.

The original suggestion came from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097163/uninstalling-android-adt), which I have up-voted.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is kind of the "tech-support-solution" but why don't you download a fresh copy of Eclipse, set up the ADT plugin and open the workspace with the new Eclipse? No need to uninstall because it isn't installed in the first place.

Worst case - it won't work but won't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem whit my eclipse a while ago, I remove the existing eclipse (big mistake) and installed a fresh version, then I downloaded the ADT Plugin from [ADT Plugin link](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html), after this go to Help -> Install New Software -> Add -> Archive -> path to your downloaded ADT plugin zip.DO NOT try to install Android 4.3( API 18 ).  Restart eclipse and I should work. At least It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the initial problem by following the advice from [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232795/cannot-access-eclipse-after-update)

to restore my backup copy of Eclipse over on top of the Eclipse installation folder. That allowed me to restart Eclipse and then use the Android SDK Manager to download the latest version of Android 4.3 and SDK 22.0.5 tools (previously not available for download). After a lengthy update process I am now getting a different error message when opening Eclipse:

"This Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 22.0.0 or above. Current version is 21.1.0.v201... Please update ADT."

When I try to check for available updates (via Help > Check for Updates...),  I get a message that "the operation cannot be completed because Object Teams Patch for JDT/Core version 2.1.1.201... is not applicable to the current configuration and will not be installed."

When I try to update the ADT plugins (via Help > Install New Software...),  I get a message that "all items (Developer Tools and NDK plugins) are already installed."

How can I get rid of this "Object Teams Patch" error message and why I am getting confusing messages from Eclipse that ADT plugins are not up to date ?

What can be done to solve this frustrating problem with Eclipse ?